# Why does the t&p valve on gas water heater open when the tank is filled?

Tags: hot-water, heater

Put a new t&p valve on my water heater and as soon as it fills up the valve opens why would this happen?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What's your water pressure, and at what pressure is the valve designed to let go?

Answer (score 1):

Either

1. The water temperature &/or pressure exceeds the valve's rating ([typically 150 psig & 210 F](http://www.wattscanada.ca/pages/support/tp.asp?catId=1159)), so it opens

Or

2. The valve is defective

If your valve is opening the second the water tank fills up, I'm assuming it hasn't had a chance to even start heating the water yet, so it must be from high pressure or a defective valve.

Possibly there's something blocking the valve from sealing, and holding it open. In that case if it were a bit of metal or rock or something it could have damaged the valve's seal / seating surfaces, so I wouldn't trust it even after removing the blockage.

I'd attach a water pressure gauge somewhere and see what your water pressure is, and just exchange the valve for a new one.

Answer (score 1):

It could be pressure is too high or possibly the wrong type of valve. Most t/p valves have a long rod sticking out. The rod is the temperature sensitive component. Check the rating of the valve. Make sure it's not 30psi. A picture would be helpful.